# Are the points inside the margin of a SVM classifier also support vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I know that support vectors are the data points which lie on either of the two margin-lines. But what about the ones that are inside the margin? Are they support vectors as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the data points "on" the margin don't contribute (they have zero weights) to the distance between the margin and the class specific data point close to the margin, which eventually ends up dictating the final selected class separation line.

Please check this great guide:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/understaing-support-vector-machine-example-code/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The support vectors are the ones which are necessary to construct the decision boundary. Hence, a support vector is a vector that lies **on** the constraints. The ones inside the do not construct the boundary, hence, they are not support vectors. In the original formulation of the SVM algorithm, it's not even possible to have such vectors because in a linearly separatable case the constraints to the following optimization problem wouldn't hold:

[image: Hard-Margin SVM]

Vapnik et al.[[1]](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~bennek/class/mmld/papers/svn.pdf) define the support vectors as the ones for which the following equation holds:

[image: Support Vectors]

The vectors inside the margin result from the regularization term of the so-called *Soft-Margin SVM*. There, miss-classifications are penalized so that it becomes possible to construct margins even with miss-classified vectors. But these erros **do not** satisfy the requirements of a support vector as the RHS of constraint is not equal to one.

[image: Soft-Margin SVM]

Comment: Thanks!! By then why are these slack variables still 'seen' as support vectors, for instance here on slide 19: [link](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect2.pdf)

Comment: Because the slacks define the margin in this case. In the soft margin case, a vector for which 1-slack is true, is a Support vector because it lies on the boundary but not inside. Sorry, forgot this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure that I understand it correctly, what exactly do you mean with  "it lies on the boundary but not inside", the point in slide 19 is inside (between the dotted and the normal line) margin. And with "1-slack is true" you mean that the 'slack' vector is correctly classified in this case?